# Wordpress. Разные стили админки для роли Подписчик

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, permissions

Первый раз делаю задачу, которая заключается в том, чтобы выводить разный внешний вид для пользователей, которые регистрируются. Для админа все, как обычно. Но для тех, кто регистрируется через сайт, нужно выводить свои стили для админ панели (личного кабинета).

Направьте пожалуйста, куда смотреть. Запросы в гугле дают результаты "как пользоваться админ панелью вп".

Я так понимаю, что начало -  это определить роль пользователя

```
current_user_can()
```

И потом грузить свои стили для админки? Правильный ли это подход со стороны безопасности и юзабилити?

Comment: судя из названия приведенная вами функция проверяет право пользователя выполнять те или иные действия. А вам, как я понял, нужно узнать роль пользователя. и причем тут безопасность?

Answer (score 1):

Roles и capabilities пользователей взаимосвязаны: https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/

Правильно как раз определять возможности через указанную вами функцию current_user_can().

Это безопасно и является хорошей практикой.